# Ancestor Query not displaying results

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, jinja2

I'm having trouble getting my [ancestor queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Ancestor_Queries) to display the links associated with [Tom's](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Ancestor_Queries) photos that are stored in the datastore. Nothing is displayed from the datastore even though there are several links in the datastore. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**main.py**

```
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os

from google.appengine.ext import db

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):          

        tom = Person(key_name='Tom')

        wedding_photo = Photo(parent=tom)
        wedding_photo.image_url='http://pinterest.com/pin/200691727117011230/'
        wedding_photo.put()

        baby_photo = Photo(parent=tom)
        baby_photo.image_url='http://pinterest.com/pin/518828819542052681/'
        baby_photo.put()

        dance_photo = Photo(parent=tom)
        dance_photo.image_url='http://pinterest.com/pin/257197828689352707/'
        dance_photo.put()

        dog_photo = Photo()
        dog_photo.image_url='http://pinterest.com/pin/279575089339614779/'
        dog_photo.put()


        photo_query = Photo.all()
        photo_query.ancestor(tom)

        message = "Photos"

        template_values = {
            'message': message,
            'photo_query': photo_query,     
        }       

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))


class PhotoStore(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        photo = Photo()
        photo.image_url = self.request.get('image_url')     
        photo.put() 
        self.redirect('/')      


class Person(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()


class Photo(db.Model):
    image_url = db.StringProperty()

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                                ('/new_photo',PhotoStore)], debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <body>                      
        <form action="/new_photo" method="post">            
            <label for="photo">Photo</label>
            <div><textarea name="image_url" rows="1" cols="60" id="image_url"></textarea></div>         
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <hr></hr>
        <div><b>{{ message }}</b></div>             
        <b>{% for p in photo_query.run(limit=5): %}</b>
        <div>{{ p }}</div>
        <b>{% endfor %}</b>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you see if you open the generated html source? I assume that the code `{{ p }}` just shows string representation of the `Photo` objects, which results in showing strings like `<__main__.Photo object at 0xfcbd9ef0>` that is interpreted as HTML tag and doesn't show in the rendered HTML.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply. {{ p }} displays nothing, no links.

Comment: oh, I see it now when I look at the page source. How do I get it to display?

Comment: wow I can't believe I made that mistake. {{ p.image_url }} resolved this issue. Thank you!